# Why does this Wordpress loop only show the last image?

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, if-statement, advanced-custom-fields

I'm new to Wordpress and I'm wondering why this loop is only displaying the last image instead of all of the images. Any reference? Here's the link, too: http://87cen.com/desmob/

```
<?php get_template_part('templates/page', 'header'); ?>
<?php get_template_part('templates/content', 'page'); ?>

<?php $temp_query = $wp_query; ?>
  <?php query_posts('showposts=10'); ?>
    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
      <div class="post" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
        <h4><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h4>
      </div>
      <?php endwhile; ?>

    <?php
      $img = get_field('image');
      if($img) { ?>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><img src="<?php echo get_field('image'); ?>"></a>
      <?php }
      ?>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Do you need to move the `endwhile` to after you display the image?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is unlikely to help anyone in the future

Comment: Why do you keep closing and reopening the PHP context around each newline? Do you _want_ those newlines to go to the client?

Comment: @JanDvorak I stated at the beginning of this thread that I'm a beginner, I'm not trying to solve code problems everywhere with this question. I understand that it's a pretty easy solution... sorry if it doesn't help anyone in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a slight issue in your logic:

```
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
  <div class="post" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
    <h4><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h4>
  </div>
  <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Your loop ends at this point; but you now go to print the image. You'll be using the image from the last iteration. All you need to do is re-arrange the loop:

```
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
  <div class="post" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
    <h4><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h4>
  </div>

  <?php 
  $img = get_field('image');
  if($img) { ?>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><img src="<?php echo get_field('image'); ?>"></a>
  <?php }
  ?>

  <?php endwhile; ?>
```

The image code is now inside the loop, and should display on each iteration.